# Where do user-supplied Kafka connectors live?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

We've got a managed Kafka setup (Confluent platform, Kafka connect 5.5.1), streaming data from ~40 topics across 8 to 10 connectors. A few weeks ago I noticed that for some of those topics, we don't have any consumers assigned. The consumers which *should* be reading from or writing to those topics are ones that our org has written and *have not changed in months*.

Looking through our connector hosts (AWS EC2 instances) I actually cannot see where our connector JAR files exist - which surprises me a lot. We've got all the other connectors there, and when I used confluent hub to install the BigQuery connector that got put under `/usr/share/java` as one would expect.

Where should home-grown connectors live on the filesystem?

For the record, when I query :8083 using the appropriate calls I can see the connector and it does have an allegedly-running task.

Answer (score 1):

They are picked from the Java `CLASSPATH` and `plugin.path`

As for where they *should* exist, is somewhere that the user account running the connect process has access to read those files.

Comment: Thankyou for this - it's what I thought was the case but if it's in the docs I completely failed to find it.

Comment: It's kinda mentioned here - https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/community.html + https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/managing/extending.html#add-additional-software

Comment: Note: `plugin.path` can be a comma-separated list of paths